# Corporate proxy with VS Code returns ECONNREFUSED

Tags: networking, visual-studio-code

I would like to use VS Code for python development. For this I need to install an extension, but searching for extensions results in an "ECONNREFUSED" error (407 when I'm using the Insiders build).
My settings.json file contains the following two lines:

```
"http.proxy": "http://username:password@proxyurl:port",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

The password does contain the @ symbol, but that's escaped with %40.
I have already double-checked for any spelling mistakes, and I'm still getting the same error. I also tried leaving out either of the two lines or both, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I had the same issue with corporate proxy and WebSense. For me proxy settings are working well. But some extensions are being installed some are not. From what I understood some URL's are being blocked by WebSense although the proxy is working well. You could also try http_proxy and https_proxy in environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Check the official documentation about [proxy-server-support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support).

As it's written, `VS Code has exactly the same proxy server support as Google Chromium`, refer the [chromium network-settings](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings) for more detais.

Assume the proxy uri is http://127.0.0.1:8118, use command like bellow:

```
code --proxy-server="http=127.0.0.1:8118;https=127.0.0.1:8118"
```

Or a simple trick with alias if you are in linux, put following line at the end of you ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile file.

```
alias code='code --proxy-server="http=127.0.0.1:8118;https=127.0.0.1:8118"'
```